# Hosted Blazor WASM with identity call from second domain return 401

Tags: identityserver4

I have a asp.net core hosted blazor wasm application with identity server 4 for authentication. I used the default template to set everything up and made only minor changes. Here is my relevant startup code:

```
        services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, SupportToolContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("name");
                    options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("name");
                    options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("role");
                    options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("role");
                });

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("role");

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(AdministratorPolicy.AdministratorPolicyName, AdministratorPolicy.IsAdminPolicy());
            options.AddPolicy(EmployeePolicy.EmployeePolicyName, EmployeePolicy.IsEmployeePolicy());
        });

        services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;

            // Lockout settings
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(LOCKOUT_DURATION);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = MAX_TRIES_BEFORE_LOCKOUT;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

            // Email Settings
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        });

        // Configure LifeSpan of Identity email tokens
        services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(IDENTITY_TOKEN_DURATION);
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
            options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = UNAUTHORIZED_STATUS_CODE;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });
```

Locally I use the development settings for the key, on Azure I have a self signed certificate for production. This works as long as I log in via my .ch Domain. When I access via my .com domain I can login as expected but on API calls I get this error:

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
  at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode () <0x3639fa8 + 0x00052> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.GetFromJsonAsyncCore[T] (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] taskResponse, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions options, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x3912f98 + 0x0012a> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ApplySupportTool.Client.Services.Implementations.UserProfileApi.GetUserProfileAsync () <0x3912300 + 0x000f8> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ApplySupportTool.Client.Components.ProfilePartial.OnInitializedAsync () <0x390f088 + 0x000d4> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync () <0x2a529e8 + 0x00154> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask (System.Threading.Tasks.Task taskToHandle) <0x33c4330 + 0x000ca> in <filename unknown>:0
```

When I check the request directly it states:

www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The issuer '[Domain].com' is invalid"

It seems that per default the issuer is set automatically to a certain value. Is there a way that I can set this manually to a single value or add multiple supported issuer?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the IssuerUri in the IdentityServer options, see this page for details:

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/options.html

You should only have one issuer in the system, otherwise it will be confusing...

In azure one issue is that you might have a public domain that the public clients see, but internally the service itself sees an internal domain namn.  Especially common if you terminate HTTPS/TLS outside your application. I think its ok to set the IssuerUri to the public domain name that clients use to communicate with it.

Comment: mh, I see. How is one supposed to support multiple endpoints? In your link they state it's not recommended to set this property and let the client determine the issuer from the host name. But it seems my server does only recognize one out of three possible issuer as valid (the azure default URL is not recognized as valid aswell..)